# SciPy - Optimize: callback(intermediate_result: OptimizeResult) what does it mean?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy-optimize

I believe it is a trivial question but I was not able to find any example and I am struggling to understand how to use this instruction for creating a callback for scipy.optimize

```
import scipy.optimize as sp
res = sp.minimize(FUN, 0.25,method='Nelder-Mead',bounds=None,callback=STOP)
```

where the callback is defined as:

```
def STOP(intermediate_result: sp.OptimizeResult):
    print('intermediate_results',intermediate_result)
    if intermediate_result.fun < 0.005:
        return StopIteration
    else:
        return 0
```

The `intermediate_result`appears to be only the optimal parameter (so it seems I am implemented the instruction callback(xk) and not callback(intermediate_result: OptimizeResult) )

I would like that my function STOP analyse the value of the returned function value and stop in case the value is smaller than 0.005

But generally I would like to understand what the guidance is saying:

> All methods except TNC, SLSQP, and COBYLA support a callable with the signature:

```
callback(intermediate_result: OptimizeResult)
```

where intermediate_result is a keyword parameter containing an OptimizeResult with attributes x and fun, the present values of the parameter vector and objective function.

Could you please help me ?

When I tried that I got:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fun'`

I tried different way to change the keyword in the function and inside the optimizer but I have not clue of what I am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In previous version of SciPy the callback parameter was the current `x` value as a `nd.array` (<= 1.9.3). In newer version it is a partial `OptimizeResult` with `fun` and `x` (1.12.0).

First upgrade to latest version of SciPy, then try this MCVE

```
from scipy import optimize

def callback(intermediate_result):
    if intermediate_result.fun < 0.5:
        raise StopIteration

optimize.minimize(optimize.rosen, x0=[0, 0, 0, 0], method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6, callback=callback)
```

Also notice that exception should be `raise`d not `return`ed.

For older versions, you have to compute the solution by yourself and raising `StopIetration` will stop the script (so you have to catch it):

```
def callback(intermediate_result):
    if optimize.rosen(intermediate_result) < 0.5:
        raise StopIteration
```

Where new version will stop the algorithm and return a solution with corresponding message:

```
#   message: `callback` raised `StopIteration`.
#   success: False
#    status: 99
#       fun: 0.4281196937835328
```

To update your WSL to the latest scipy, issue the following command:

```
python -m pip install -U --user scipy
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it is the problem. Unfortunately, I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL and it seems I am not able to update Scipy from version 1.08. This is indicated as the newest version.

Comment: @Alessandro, Have you tried `python -m pip install -U scipy --user`? See the update.

Comment: Yes it is working now. I was using <pre>  sudo apt-get upgrade python3-scipy <code> without success. I used your sintax by changing python with python3 and I was able to install it.